# Parallax bug in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, parallax

I have got a **Chrome only bug** in a website using parallax. The site is http://apple.dragon.com.

The bug is evident when you scroll over the first parallax'ed image (the section with the copy: "3x faster than typing"). As I scroll down, the background image is hidden by a white background before reappearing again as I scroll further.

This bug does not appear in Firefox, Safari or IE9+.

I am struggling to find related issues on here. When I'm using Chrome Developer Tools, I am seeing some strange behaviour which is also slowing my progress.

Has anyone come across this before or know of a solution? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Cannot replicate on Chrome/Debian. What OS are you on?

Answer (score 4):

I saw the problem but i'm also stumped at what causes it.
However, i managed to fix it in Chrome dev tools by applying a background-color to `#content #second`.

```
media="all"
@media only screen and (min-width: 1030px)
#content #second {
    background: url('https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dragondictate/images/lockup-fast-bg-large.jpg') no-repeat 50% 0 fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Strange

Comment: YES! You little beauty. This appears to have fixed it. There was no colour set for the background for this div and adding it has fixed the issue. I have absolutely no idea why that would be the case, but the important thing is that it's fixed. Thank you Andy!!